# Linking SDL2 - CLion - Ubuntu 16.04 - G++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, clion

## Background info

As the title says, I am on Ubuntu 16.04 using CLion and G++, and I am unable to link SDL2.

SDL2.h is found in the project at `External Libraries/Header Search Paths/include/SDL2`. This seems to link to `/usr/include/SDL2`.

So, with the header file found, I can `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` without any issues. Yet, when I try to make use of SDL2 with something like, `SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING )`, I get an `undefined reference`.

If I compile from terminal with `g++ main.cpp -lSDL2 -o test` I have no errors. But, if I compile from terminal with `g++ main.cpp -o test`, then I have the same error as CLion!

## Question

How do I link SDL2 to Cmake? Did I add this flag `-lsdl2` to the CMake file correctly? If I added it properly, then what am I missing?

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(untitled2)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lSDL2")

add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to search for the SDL2 package and link it to the target.  Don't use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for this (or any sort of linking/header paths/etc); try the following:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED SDL2)
 : 
add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled2
  PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2
)
```

This will pull in the appropriate for headers etc.  Note, this does not automatically include `SDL_main` or other libraries, which you may need or want in addition.

Additionally, for older versions of SDL2, `SDL2::SDL2` may not work, and you may just want `SDL2`.  I would recommend upgrading if this is the case, though.

Comment: The original solution did not work, but I modified it slightly and it did! I removed the namespace from ```SDL2::SDL2```, so the command looked like ```target_link_libraries(untitled2 PRIVATE SDL2)```. After that everything compiled just fine. Has your original command worked in the past?

Comment: This is what I meant by "Additionally, for older versions of SDL2, SDL2::SDL2 may not work, and you may just want SDL2".  Again, this is due to your SDL2 being old; you should probably upgrade.

Comment: Odd, I installed it via ```sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev```. Running ```dpkg -l | grep sdl2``` on my system suggests that my version is 2.0.4 or 2.0.0. The latest version out as of 9/18/2018 is 2.0.8, and I don't see anyway to upgrade on my system.

Comment: Yeah, you might need to dist-upgrade (looks like 2.0.8 is in newer ubuntu) or just build it yourself, which is what I do.  This is nice for a controlled build and stable dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-lSDL2")
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the answer @rpav gave. This project has the minimal amount of code necessary to test that SDL2 was in fact working with CLion.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(untitled2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED SDL2)

add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(untitled2 PRIVATE SDL2)
```

Most of the CMake file is provided by CLion. The only additional lines of code are `find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED SDL2)` and `target_link_libraries(untitled2 PRIVATE SDL2)`. To clarify, `untitled2`, is the name of my project.