# Undefined reference to SDL2 functions with CLION in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl-2, clion

it's my first post on stackoverflow so be understanding please :)

I'm using CLion on Ubutun in a C project, all works fine until I started with SDL2 ...
I have the error : undefined reference to « SDL_CreateWindow » and all the SDL2 functions I want to use.
I read lot of sames errors but on Windows and with Ubuntu, no one ...

I'm a beginner in Makefiles and C in general

That's my code :
main.c

```
#include "main.h"
#include "sdl_functions.h"
    
int main() {
    int (*pieces) [10][10] = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

sdl_functions.c

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "sdl_functions.h"
    
void displayPiece(){
    
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;    
        
        window=SDL_CreateWindow("TESTWINDOW", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 800, 0);//error undefined reference to SDL_CreateWindow
}
```

And that's is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(project_name C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-lSDL2")
add_executable(project_name main.c main.h sdl_functions.c sdl_functions.h)
```

Comment: the posted question seems to be missing the contents of `sdl_functions.h` How are we to know if the root of the problem is simply that the `sdl_functions.h` file is missing the needed prototypes for the functions in `sdl_functions.c`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, I find a solution in this post
[Linking SDL2 - CLion - Ubuntu 16.04 - G++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338274/linking-sdl2-clion-ubuntu-16-04-g)

you have to open yout CMakeLists.txt

and modify this file like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(project_name C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED SDL2)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-lSDL2")
add_executable(project_name main.c main.h sdl_functions.c sdl_functions.h)
target_link_libraries(project_name PRIVATE SDL2)
```

Now I have an exit code 0, so for the moment it seem to works